# I am looking for an alternative solution to openlayers for satellite imagery in QGIS?

Tags: openlayers-2, print-composer, qgis-openlayers-plugin, satellite, basemap

Does anyone have any other suggestions for sources of satellite imagery on QGIS? Openlayers is becoming extremely temperamental in QGIS 2.6 (Google imagery not bothering to work anymore, Can't zoom in below 1:2000 on all layers, Doesn't work at all with print composer). There must be another solution to having a decent satellite image?

Can anyone point me to any alternative sources or solutions?

Comment: This question is too broad to my mind. Please specify the parameters of the imagery you would like to use and a price to pay for it.

Comment: I assume he wants it for free and for the whole world like in the openlayers plugin.

Comment: @GeologyTom, this [similar question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/satellite-imagery-providers/126410#126410) may have some useful responses for you. Specifically, you might be interested in the [MapBox "Cloudless Atlas"](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/126410/4968), which has only been available for about a year. Unfortunately it's not free, but you can get it for as low as $5 a month. And depending on the volume of map loads you expect (where 1 load = 15 tiles), the next plan is available for $49 a month.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ESRI imagery in QGIS, just add it as a WMTS:

Add WMS/WMTS Layer > NEW > enter a Name and the URL below, press OK > Connect > select a Tileset and Add it to the map

http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml